# Understanding CPP specific Class declaration and resulting error

Tags: c++

My CPP understanding is not good enough to understand the following Class declaration

```
#define Default_n_datapoints 10

class MeanAngle {
   public:
       MeanAngle(std::size_t a_nDataPoints = Default_n_datapoints) : 
         NDATAPOINTS (a_nDataPoints) {};
       virtual ~MeanAngle();
       virtual void AddSample(const float a_fSample);
       virtual float GetAverage() const;
  protected:
       const std::size_t NDATAPOINTS;
   private:
       float ring[NDATAPOINTS];
       uint8_t i;
   };
```

and in particular: If `NDATAPOINTS` is **const**, why can't I use it dimensioning `ring[]`? `ring[NDATAPOINTS]` gives me an error:

```
A non-static member reference must be relative to a specific object
```

How should I correct the declaration? What I want is that the initialisation parameter `a_nDataPoints` to be used as dimension in the ring buffer.

Comment: Replace `#define Default_n_datapoints 10` -> `static constexpr std::size_t NDATAPOINTS{10ul};`.  #define is not the nicest way to declare constants (#define is a macro and has not type), and it should have been NDATAPOINTS.  In general if you don't know how many items your `ring` will hold, change it to std::vector<float> which is an array that can resize at runtime.

Comment: `NDATAPOINTS` is `const`, but still every object could have a different value, and size of type must be the same for every object of that type.

Comment: Whilst `NDATAPOINTS` is a constant it's not a compile time constant and can't be used as an array size. If you want a variable sized array use `std:: vector`

Answer (score 9):

A specified array size must be a ***compile-time*** constant. That is, its value must be known at compile time. If you pretend that you are a C++ compiler, yourself, look at this code, and attempt to figure out what actual, integer, value `NDATAPOINTS` is, you will fall far short of your lofty goals.

The only thing that `const` gives you is that a `const` value is a run-time constant. It never changes *once it exists*. That's not the same thing as a compile-time constant. A compile-time constant would be a `constexpr`.

Answer (score 0):

If you will always use this class with compile-time constant as argument, then you can make it template:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

static constexpr std::size_t Default_n_datapoints = 10ul;

template<std::size_t N = Default_n_datapoints>
class MeanAngle {
    public:
        MeanAngle() {};
        virtual ~MeanAngle();
        virtual void AddSample(const float a_fSample);
        virtual float GetAverage() const;
    protected:
       const std::size_t NDATAPOINTS = N;
    private:
       float ring[N];
       uint8_t i;
};
```

You can then use it like that:

```cpp
MeanAngle<5> a;
MeanAngle<> b; // Default size will be used
```